# Angular component properties is not updating inside HTTPRequest subscription

Tags: angular

I would like to show/hide messages on a popup using `<div *ngIf="hasFormErrors">{{messageBody}}</div>`. I have defined two public properties `hasFormErrors = false;` and `messageBody = '';` at the beginning of the component. The issue I am having is these properties are not getting updated when the request comes back with an HTTPErrorResponse and therefore the error message is not showing up on the popup. Inside the `errorMsg` handler it shows both of the properties are undefined. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```js
createObject(requestBody: NewObjectRequestBody) {
    const apiUrl = <some-url>;
    const body = requestBody;
    const httpHeaders = this.httpUtils.getHTTPHeaders();
    return this.http.post<NewObjectRequestBody>(apiUrl, body, { headers: httpHeaders });
}
```

```js
onSubmit() {
    this.hasFormErrors = false;
    const controls = this.objectCreateForm.controls;
    /** check form */
    if (this.objectCreateForm.invalid) {
        Object.keys(controls).forEach(controlName => 
           controls[controlName].markAsTouched()
        );
        this.messageBody = 'Required fields need to be filled out.';
        this.hasFormErrors = true;
        return;
    }

    const newObjectParams = this.prepareObject();
    this.sampleService.createObject(newObjectParams).subscribe(
        responseData => {
            console.log(responseData);
        },
        errorMsg => {
            this.messageBody = errorMsg;
            this.hasFormErrors = true;
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Did you get values inside the error message handler? did you debug it?

Comment: Yes. The pop up is a form and it has some dropdowns. Interestingly, I can see the message when I click on one of the dropdowns. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Could you provide sample in stackblitz?

Comment: No sure how I am going to make the API calls on stackblitz. I have updated the `onSubmit()` on this post, hope this helps. It is now showing the complete function that I have on my code. It shows the error right away if the form is invalid but for the HttpErrorResponse I need to click on one of the form controls.

Comment: Do you have any condition like, show error message if form is invalid?

Comment: yes, please look at the `onSubmit()` function on the post.

Comment: Then you have to set form invalid manually inside error message handler.

Comment: myForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });

Comment: Still does not work. I still need to select one of the form controls to display the message.

Comment: Okay then, Make one the field as markAsTouched;

Comment: No luck. The issue is inside of the errorMsg block, it shows all the properties are undefined. Now I defined a new property `errorRes: any` and I am trying to set `errorMsg` to this property inside of the errorMsg block but it's not working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution#1:

I had to remove `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` from `@Component`.

Solution#2:

I was able to find a solution to my issue. Here is how I solved it:

First, added id `#objectName` to one of the form controls.

```
<input #objectName matInput placeholder="Object Name" formControlName="name" />
```

Then, in the component added a `@ViewChild` for the input element.

```
@ViewChild('objectName', {static: false}) objectName: ElementRef;
```

Then, updated the `errorMsg` block:

```
errorMsg => {
    this.messageBody = this.formatHTTPResponse(errorMsg).message;
    this.hasFormErrors = true;
    this.clickObjectName();
}
```

and lastly, added the `clickObjectName()` function:

```
clickObjectName() {
    this.batchObject.nativeElement.click();
}
```